# Display FormArray in another FormArray in Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to display form array inside another formarray but it gives me an error, Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

here is my code

```
addInventoryFormGroup() {
    this.addInventoryForm = this.fb.group({
        addInventoryFieldsList: this.fb.array([this.buildAddInventoryFields()]),
    });
}

buildAddInventoryFields(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        buildTableFields: this.fb.array([this.buildAddInventoryTableFields()]),
        quantity: '',
        section: '',
        row: '',
    })
}

buildAddInventoryTableFields(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        unitCost: '',
        faceValue: '',
    })
}

get addInventoryFieldsList(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.addInventoryForm.get('addInventoryFieldsList');
}
```

here is my html code for it

```
<form [formGroup]="addInventoryForm">
     <div class="reactive-form" formArrayName="addInventoryFieldsList" *ngFor="let address of addInventoryFieldsList.controls; let i = index;">
          <div [formGroupName]="i">
               <div formArrayName="buildTableFields" *ngFor="let fields of addInventoryFieldsList.controls.buildTableFields.controls; let x = index;">
                    <span [formGroupName]="x">ABC</span>
               </div>   
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Please help me to fix this error

Comment: Can you also post code of `addInventoryFieldsList` property?

Comment: it is just a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i don't see you declared `addInventoryFieldsList` i suspect that is your problem.

You should write `addInventoryForm.controls.addInventoryFieldsList` to access 
`addInventoryFieldsList` FormArray control.

The following should work for you:

```
<form [formGroup]="addInventoryForm">
    <div class="reactive-form" formArrayName="addInventoryFieldsList" *ngFor="let address of addInventoryForm.controls.addInventoryFieldsList.controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <div formArrayName="buildTableFields" *ngFor="let fields of address.controls.buildTableFields.controls; let x = index;">
                <span [formGroupName]="x">ABC</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also note i use `address.controls.buildTableFields.controls` to loop over nested controls

**Update:**

As it turned out you have defined addInventoryFieldsList getter. So here is updated template:

```
<form [formGroup]="addInventoryForm">
    <div class="reactive-form" formArrayName="addInventoryFieldsList" *ngFor="let address of addInventoryFieldsList.controls; let i = index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <div formArrayName="buildTableFields" *ngFor="let fields of address.controls.buildTableFields.controls; let x = index;">
                <span [formGroupName]="x">ABC</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/WsXrq6fufRFoT1siG9nG)**

Comment: i declared addInventoryFieldsList, i do not have any error if i do not try to display nested forArray

Comment: Updated example https://ng-run.com/edit/WsXrq6fufRFoT1siG9nG It still works for me

Comment: yes you are right, its working there but still not on my machine :(

Comment: I don't think so. Something is different) Can you recreate example?

Comment: html and ts code is 100%, now its display it for 1 sec and then gives same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170777/discussion-between-muhammad-arslan-and-yurzui).

Answer (score 1):

This post might help you...
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/
Be sure to load the form before using it

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.addInventoryForm = this.fb.group({
    addInventoryFieldsList: this.fb.array([this.buildAddInventoryFields()]),
   });
}... follow with your methods
```

HTML

```
   <form [formGroup]="addInventoryForm">
 <div class="reactive-form" formArrayName="addInventoryFieldsList" *ngFor="let address of addInventoryForm.get('addInventoryFieldsList').controls; let i = index;">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
           <div formArrayName="buildTableFields" *ngFor="let fields of addInventoryForm.get('addInventoryFieldsList').controls; let x = index;">
                <span [formGroupName]="x">ABC</span>
           </div>   
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Add two groups to `addInventoryFieldsList` and enjoy error) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dy7mz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui means ?

Comment: @yurzui not sure if your update to my stackblitz was what Arslan meant, the question didn't give much information, but your answer was very rude. Be more polite next time!

Comment: Sorry if my answer was rude for you. I just wanted to say that your nested ngFor is not correct. I will be more polite next time

Comment: I think that to be rude is to downvote and don't say what's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please check addInventoryFieldsList which might not be a declared variable in your ts file.

Comment: its declared, everything is fine if i do not try to show nested formarray

Comment: Can you try with  <div formArrayName="buildTableFields" *ngFor="let fields of address.controls.buildTableFields.controls; let x = index;">
                    <span [formGroupName]="x">ABC</span>
               </div>